# unnecessary 1=1 in select query

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

Below query is used in one of my product. I am not able to understand why `1=1` is mentioned. it is always going to true.

```
select * from emp;
select * from emp where 1=1;
```

As per my understanding both are same. What could be the intention of developer to put `1=1` in below query? he can simply write `where` condition in one of the `and` condition.

```
SELECT   msi.concatenated_segments item_code,
mmt.transaction_date,
mtt.transaction_type_name,
mmt.transaction_quantity,
mcd.prior_cost,
mcd.new_cost
   FROM 
mtl_cst_actual_cost_details mcd,
mtl_system_items_kfv msi,
mtl_material_transactions mmt,
mtl_COST_types mtt
WHERE 1 = 1  -------------------------------------------------This I am refering
AND mcd.inventory_item_id = msi.inventory_item_id
AND mcd.organization_id = msi.organization_id
AND mcd.transaction_id = mmt.transaction_id
AND mmt.inventory_item_id = msi.inventory_item_id
AND mmt.organization_id = msi.organization_id
AND mmt.transaction_type_id = mtt.transaction_type_id
ORDER BY mcd.creation_date DESC;
```

Comment: But – as Guy has correctly observed – the people who now do this day have probably become conditioned by what they've seen by *programmatically generated* SQL statements in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`where 1 = 1` is always true, so both queries are equivalent. Most databases are able to identify that when parsing the query, so there is no performance penalty involved.

A common reason why applications use this dummy `where` clause is that it makes it easy to further concatenate conditions in the `where` clause.

Starting from string `'where 1 = 1'`, the application can concatenate as many `and` predicates as necessary. Otherwise, it would need to check if a condition was already added in the query string before deciding if it is necessary to put `'and'` before the condition.

Answer (score 2):

If the query is generated dynamically, the logic to add the where conditions is a bit simpler if there is a first `1=1`.
You can just append them like:

```
STATIC QUERY
AND WHERE_CONDITION_1
AND WHERE_CONDITION_2
AND WHERE_CONDITION_3
...
```

And they are not depending on the position.

I think some ORM systems use this approach as well.

Answer (score 1):

Like I commented above – many programmers today are entirely used to "ORM's," and the sometimes-nonsensical yet grammatically-correct SQL clauses that are sometimes generated by them.  And actually: "no harm, no foul."

`WHERE 1=1` is of course a perfectly-valid `WHERE` clause if your internal logic (buried somewhere within the bowels of the ORM in question ...) was designed in such a way that you *have to* produce one. ‍♂️

.. or, maybe, if you decide that *your programming* somehow needs to `join(' AND ')` a whole bunch of clauses, and you decide that you need to stitch a "dummy clause" in front of them.  (Although, of course, you actually don't.)